# Is there a way to detect if a debugger is attached to another process from C#?

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a program that `Process.Start()` another program, and it shuts it down after N seconds.

Sometimes I choose to attach a debugger to the started program. In those cases, I don't want the process shut down after N seconds.

I'd like the host program to detect if a debugger is attached or not, so it can choose to not shut it down.

**Clarification**: I'm not looking to detect if a debugger is attached to *my* process, I'm looking to detect if a debugger is attached to the process I spawned.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will need to [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) down to [CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679280%28VS.85%29.aspx). This requires a handle to the target process, which you can get from Process.Handle.

Answer (score 179):

```
if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this tell me if a debugger is attached to the Host process? I'm looking for a way to figure out if the spawned process is being debugged.

Comment: I see, sorry for misunderstanding your question. I believe the spawned process is the only one which can query that information. If you set up some form of inter-process communication, that would allow the original process to poll for the debugger state.

Answer (score 21):

### Is the *current* process being debugged?

```
var isDebuggerAttached = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached;
```

### Is *another* process being debugged?

```
Process process = ...;
bool isDebuggerAttached;
if (!CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(process.Handle, out isDebuggerAttached)
{
    // handle failure (throw / return / ...)
}
else
{
    // use isDebuggerAttached
}


/// <summary>Checks whether a process is being debugged.</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The "remote" in CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent does not imply that the debugger
/// necessarily resides on a different computer; instead, it indicates that the 
/// debugger resides in a separate and parallel process.
/// <para/>
/// Use the IsDebuggerPresent function to detect whether the calling process 
/// is running under the debugger.
/// </remarks>
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(
    SafeHandle hProcess,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] ref bool isDebuggerPresent);
```

### Within a Visual Studio extension

```
Process process = ...;
bool isDebuggerAttached = Dte.Debugger.DebuggedProcesses.Any(
    debuggee => debuggee.ProcessID == process.Id);
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I was having the same issue and realized if you have a pointer to the EnvDTE, you can check if the process is in [Dte.Debugger.DebuggedProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debugger.debuggedprocesses.aspx):

```
foreach (EnvDTE.Process p in Dte.Debugger.DebuggedProcesses) {
  if (p.ProcessID == spawnedProcess.Id) {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

The CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent call only checks if the process is being natively debugged, I believe - it won't work for detecting managed debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me is Debugger.IsAttached as described here: http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip32.asp