# See if other assembly is being debugged

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process

We have an assembly, lets call it `Foo.exe`. This executable will be started by another application like `Bar1.exe` or `Bar2.exe`.

If `Foo.exe` runs it checks every 10 seconds if a `Bar1` or `Bar2` process is running. If not it cleans up some things and shuts down.

This works on the normal user scenario. But if we develop we have one big problem:
The application cannot see if the application `Bar1` or `Bar2` is under debugging or not, in both cases `Bar.svhost.exe` is available in the task manager.

That means, if the `Bar.svhost.exe` will be ignored, `Foo.exe` ends during debugging process, this is not possible.

But if the `Bar.svhost.exe` will be seen, the `Foo.exe` never ends, we have to kill is manually but then it was not cleaned properly.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

(Ending the `Foo.exe` out of `Bar1` or `Bar2` is not possible, because multiple `Bar1` or `Bar2` can be run on the machine but `Foo` just have to run once. Therefore the `Foo.exe` has to check itself. And the "Kill" the process will be let it cleaning up)

Add:
Here an pseudo code example of the problem

```
//Bar1.exe and Bar2.exe
void Main()
{
    if (!FooIsRunning())
        StartFoo();
    DoSomething();
}

//Foo.exe
void Main()
{
    Initialize();
    while (BarIsRunning());
    Cleanup();
}

private bool BarIsRunning()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    if (processes.Any(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("Bar.exe"))
        return true;

    var vshostProcess = processes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("Bar.vshost.exe");
    return vshostProcess != null && ProcessIsDebugging(process);
}

private bool ProcessIsDebugging(Process process)
{
    // How to...
    return true;
}
```

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188201/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-debugger-is-attached-to-a-process-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Do you specifically want to know if it's being debugged, or do you just need a solution to "`Foo` should exit after the last instance of `Bar1` or `Bar2` exits (of which multiple instances may run)"?

Comment: Out of Foo I need to know if Bar1 or Bar2 runs in the debugger or not. In other words, Foo has to know if any instance of Bar1 or Bar2 exists.

Comment: You're focusing on the debugging aspect - but I'm still not sure if that's vital, or just one example you've come up with where a simpler technique isn't working (and I don't know if you're accounting for foreign `Bar1` programs with the same executable name)

Comment: I'm focusing on the debugging aspect because just this once scenario is problematic. At runtime on the customer machine everything works very well. But we would like to have a clean shutdown out of the debugging session as well. Our first idea was to let Bar telling Foo "Please Shut Down", but without a special communication way like WCF we have no clean way, therefore we say that Foo has to care about itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if *other* applications have a debugger attached, use [CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms679280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I've written an extension method for the processes:

```
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern bool CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(IntPtr hProcess, ref bool isDebuggerPresent);

    public static bool IsDebuggerAttached(this Process process)
    {
        try
        {
            var isDebuggerAttached = false;
            CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(process.Handle, ref isDebuggerAttached);

            return isDebuggerAttached;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked [Debugger.IsAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) ?

Comment: Seems interesting. If in Foo I have the Process Bar1, can I check if Bar1 is attached to the debugger? Foo itself never will be debugged

Comment: Foe example, Foo does like this
void Main()
{
    if (IsBarRunning())
        ShutDown();
}

private static bool IsBarRunning()
{
    return Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("Bar"));
}

Comment: The debugger attaches to a _process_.  Any code executing in the context of that process, in any assembly, in any thread, should see the same value for `Debugger.IsAttached`.

Comment: Ya, but If I see this right I can check Debugger.IsAttached only directly in the code of Bar1.exe or Bar2.exe. From this side I cannot handle this because out of Bar I cannot close Foo properly. Therefore Foo has to check if Bar is being debugged. I need someting like `barProcess.IsDebugging`

Answer (score 0):

I think I solve the problem. I figured out that the MainWindowTitle is different if Bar1 or Bar2 will be debugged or not.
Until debugging the MainWindowTitle of the Bar1.vshost.exe will be the real application title, if not the MainWindowTitle is empty.

Foo.exe

```
private static bool IsLastClientClosed()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    var debuggingProcesses = processes.Where(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("Bar1.vshost") || p.ProcessName.Contains("Bar2.vshost")).ToList();
    if (debuggingProcesses.Any())
        return !DebuggingRuns(debuggingProcesses);

    return processes.Any(p => p.ProcessName.StartsWith("Bar1") || p.ProcessName.StartsWith("Bar2"));
}

private static bool DebuggingRuns(IEnumerable<Process> processes)
{
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                return true;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```