# #if Debug doesn't makes a button disabled if not debug

Tags: c#, debugging

In my wpf app I have some button that I want it to be enable if I'm in debug I mean if I run my app via F5.

and I want it to be disabled if I'm not in debug, I mean ctrl+F5

XAML:

```
<Button  x:Name="ArrowRight" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Code behind:

```
public MyClass()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  #if DEBUG
    ArrowRight.IsEnabled = true;
  #endif
}
```

but the button is always enabled, if I run F5 or even ctrl+F5

So I tried to change this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCKTI.png)

to "Release" but if I build my solution it tells that I'm missing some Locator.dll

How to use `#if Debug` correctly?

Comment: According to this [post here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47857/setting-buttons-isenabled-to-false-does-not-disable-button) you need to bind the value. Hardcoding it doesn't work.

Comment: you're using the debug directive correctly; implementation is fine. correct whatever the Locator.dll issue you're having with the release build and you can confirm that. `F5` or `CTRL+F5` have no barring - that is, it doesn't matter if you're attempting to attach a debugger.  you're still building in `Debug` either way.

Comment: There seems to be a side effect when you set the Command property. Make sure the Command property is either not set or is corretly set and the IsEnabled property is defined AFTER the Command property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> are independent of debug/release mode build.

In a dropdown at the top you can select Debug or Release configuration. In debug mode the "DEBUG" symbol is defined, so your `#if` works (the code inside is compiled). In Release mode it isn't defined, so your line of code isn't compiled. It is even shown greyed out.

Both F5 and Ctrl+F5 run in whatever configuration is selected: F5 just attaches the debugger while Ctrl+F5 doesn't. You may see a warning that you are trying to debug an application that is built in release mode.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188201/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-debugger-is-attached-to-a-process-from-c) to detect the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

you're using the debug directive correctly; implementation is fine.

Correct whatever the "Locator.dll" issue you're having with the release build and you can confirm that.

doing `F5` or `CTRL+F5` has no barring to the build - it does not matter if you are attempting to attach a debugger while running after the build, you're still building in Debug either way.

---

Alternative, you can reverse the logic here and see if it applies.

make the button enabled by default.

```
<Button  x:Name="ArrowRight" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

disable it when with debug directive

```
public MyClass()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  #if DEBUG
    ArrowRight.IsEnabled = false;
  #endif
}
```