# In VS, is there a pre-processor directive that differentiates F5 vs. Ctrl + F5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, is there a pre-processor directive that differentiates running the app with F5 vs. Ctrl + F5? I'm aware about detecting DEBUG vs. RELEASE with "#if DEBUG", but I'm looking to detect the execution mode (F5 or Ctrl + F5).

Comment: I don't know for a fact, but I would find it highly surprising if there was

Comment: There likely isn't a preprocessor for that (since it's a runtime variable, not something you know at compile time), but you do have `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish, I mean why do you need to detect those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no pre-processor directive that distinguish between "Run" (Ctrl+f5) and "Debug" (F5) modes of starting an executable. The exact same executable can be started both ways, including running both ways at the same time.

Depending on you needs and settings:

- see if debugger is attached ([Is there a way to detect if a debugger is attached to another process from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188201/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-debugger-is-attached-to-another-process-from-c)). Limitation of this approach is that debugger may be attached later than initial launch, but possibly before your own code starts. Also it detects any debugger, not just VS instance where you compiled the code.
- try to detect if code JITed without optimizations (you need to investigate how to do so). This will not work if "suppress optimizations on assembly load" option turned off in VS.